# mysql2 async/await undefined rows and fields node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, mysql2

why this query below returns undefined in rows and field even the user table has data? how can i use the promise version properly in typescript. any help would gladly appreciate. Thank you...

**code**

```
import mysql from 'mysql2';
import 'dotenv/config';
import bluebird from 'bluebird';

//? this all configuration for database connection
const connection: any = mysql.createConnection({
  host: process.env.DB_HOSTNAME,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  database: process.env.DATABASE,
  Promise: bluebird,
});

//! test connection - required
const testConnection = async () => {
  try {
    //? output to the console the query value
    let [rows, fields]: [any, any] = await connection.execute(
      'SELECT * FROM user',
    );
    console.log(rows, fields);
    console.log('successfully connected to database');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};


testConnection();
```

****Console Output****
`undefined undefined`
`successfully connected to database`

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the mysql [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-promise-wrapper), I have two suggestions:

- I see that you need to change what you are importing.
- Also you need to await on the `createConnection` call as well.

```
// get the client
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
 
// get the promise implementation, we will use bluebird
const bluebird = require('bluebird');
  
const testConnection = async () => {
  try {
    // create the connection, specify bluebird as Promise
    const connection = await mysql.createConnection({host:'localhost', user: 'root', database: 'test', Promise: bluebird});
    // query database
    const [rows, fields] = await connection.execute('SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `name` = ? AND `age` > ?', ['Morty', 14]);

    console.log(rows, fields);
    console.log('successfully connected to database');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: You can't use await in a non async function as you're doing above

Comment: Posting faulty code and using a library with multiple dependencies in order to do a simple await. Bad code practice.

Comment: updated w.r.t comments, my bad. Also, just using whatever libraries OP is already using